# How does one link an image to a VR URL using a-frame?

Tags: aframe, webvr

I have seen several examples that fall short of a simple linked image using aframe. The closest I found was a link-traversal example at https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/master/examples/showcase/link-traversal/index.html, however that does not work on the Oculus Go (guessing because it is more complex than needed) and images are not being used to link. I would settle for the non-image links, but even then images are not showing in the circle and when clicked in VR I am taken out of VR mode. I am surprise something as simple as a image-based weblink is so difficult using a-frame. Perhaps I am missing something simple? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can check out the `link`'s [source code](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/v0.8.0/src/components/link.js#L161), utilizing the "link" part

```
window.location = this.data.url;
```

and throw it into an a-frame component:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent("weblink", {
  schema: {
    url: {
      default: ""
    }
  },
  init: function() {
    this.el.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      window.location = this.data.url;
    })
  }
})
```

on click - change the window location to the desired url. Throw it on any aframe entity:

```
<a-box position="-1 0.5 -3" rotation="0 45 0" color="#4CC3D9" 
       weblink="url: https://google.com"></a-box>
```

---

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/skLvfgwy/1/), although you need to copy the code elsewhere since jsfiddle won't allow changing the `window.location` to another origin.

Comment: Also keep in mind that in-VR navigation only works in Firefox, Supermedium, Oculus Browser and Samsung Internet.

Comment: The problem is, I am being brought out of VR mode with each check (both on Firefox and Oculus browser).